# How can I open up rmarkdown script in rstudio

Tags: r, r-markdown

I try to write a report using rmarkdown, but I have tried all the methods to download the lastest version rmarkdown package. When I try to open up the rmarkdown script, it shows that

> Required version package could not be found:
>   rmarkdown 1.2 is required but 1.1 is available
>   Check that getOption("repos") refers to CRAN repository that contains the needed package versions.

Some of the code I have tried:

```
install.packages("rmarkdown")
update.packages("rmarkdown")
install_github("rstudio/rmarkdown")
```

> And my R version is 3.3.2 and my rstudio is already the lastest version now, which I think might be the problem coming from.

Comment: Make sure you're using a functional CRAN mirror. Most likely updating RStudio itself will take care of the problem, though; I think it installs a few basic packages including rmarkdown to make itself function.

Comment: The problem is my Rstudio is already the newest version

Comment: If that's true, R is updated, and your CRAN mirror is functioning, you wouldn't be getting that error.

Comment: I also download the package manually into the win-library

Comment: @victordongy It's good that you found the answer, but you should not edit it in the question. You can post an answer even if you are the asker. Please post your last lines as an answer.

Comment: Thanks scoa, I would do that

Answer (score 4):

> I am glad the problem being solved! Instead of keep trying installing packages, I updated my cran URL to cran.project. And learnt some function of adding repos, thank you all! The code follows as :

```
local({r <- getOption("repos"); r["CRAN"] <- "https://cran.r-project.org/"; options(repos = r)})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a total reach, but I've been teaching R and RStudio and have seen this happen a lot!

Make sure the Markdown file you're creating has extension ".Rmd"

Many of my students have named their Markdown files something like "Foo.Rproj".

Comment: I cannot open up markdown script, it is not the problem of saving the markdown file or opening a file....

Comment: So have you met similar situation? Thanks